# How to find ipv6 addresses of connected devices to my Linux PC?

Tags: networking, ipv6, arp

I can see all connected devices to my Linux PC with:

```
cat /proc/net/arp
```

But this show only the IPv4 addresses and MAC of the connected devices. There is no IPv6 addresses.

How to find the IPv6 addresses of the connected Devices?

Comment: `/proc/net/arp` doesn't list devices connected to your PC.  It shows a list of devices on your subnet for which your PC has done/seen an ARP request for.  If you want to see which devices are connected to your PC, then you need `netstat` or similar (which will automatically show both ipv4 and ipv6 devices).  ipv6 doesn't use ARP (it uses NDP).

Comment: Hmmmm....`netstat -a` does not work?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see all devices which have established connections to your machine, you can use

```
ss -t
```

to see all IPv4 and IPV6 tcp connections.

---

If you want the IPv6 equivalent of `cat /proc/net/arp` (that is, see all the machines on the local network for which you have cached the layer 2 address), use

```
ip -6 neigh
```

or simply

```
ip neigh
```

for the combined IPv4 and IPv6 neighboring nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest command is to list out all connections is the `ss | less`, but to view only tcp or udp or unix connections use the `-t` that is,

```
ss -t
```

this should show you all IPv4 and IPV6 tcp connections.

---

- To display only IPv4 socket connections use the `-f inet` or `-4` option.

  ss -tl -f inet
  or

  ss -tl -4
- While to display only IPv6 connections use the `-f inet6` or `-6` option.

  ss -tl6
  or

  ss -finet6

  ---

Or simply for the combined IPv4 and IPv6 neighboring nodes use

```
ip neighbour
```

Which will shows the current neighbour table in kernel.

But **NOTE** as you've seen in the comment: `/proc/net/arp` doesn't list devices connected to your PC. It shows a list of devices on your subnet for which your PC has done/seen an ARP request for. If you want to see which devices are connected to your PC, then you need `netstat` or similar (which will automatically show both IPV4 and IPV6 devices). IPV6 doesn't use ARP (it uses NDP)